# Kotlin coroutines: Switching context when testing an Android Presenter

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I've started using kotlin coroutines in my Android project recently, but I have somewhat of a problem with it. Many would call it a code smell.

I'm using an MVP architecture where the coroutines are started in my presenter like this:

```
// WorklistPresenter.kt
...
override fun loadWorklist() {
    ...
    launchAsync { mViewModel.getWorklist() }
    ...
```

The `launchAsync`function is implemented this way (in my BasePresenter class that my WorklistPresenter class extends):

```
@Synchronized
protected fun launchAsync(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    return launch(UI) { block() }
}
```

The problem with this is that I'm using a UI coroutine context that depends on the Android Framework. I can't change this to another coroutine context without running into `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`. To be able to unit test this I've created a copy of my BasePresenter with a different implementation of `launchAsync`:

```
protected fun launchAsync(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    runBlocking { block() }
    return mock<Job>()
}
```

To me this is a problem because now my BasePresenter has to be maintained in two places. So my question is. How can I change my implementation to support easy testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d recommend to extract the `launchAsync` logic into a separate class, which you can simply mock in your tests.

```
class AsyncLauncher{

    @Synchronized
    protected fun execute(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
        return launch(UI) { block() }
    }

}
```

It should be part of your activity constructor in order to make it replaceable.

Comment: The best solution I believe.

Comment: Im sorry it’s so boring 

Comment: Well that's not your fault. Sometimes programming just is ;)

Comment: @s1m0nw1 where to write the class and how to use it. I am using MVVM pattern and new to writing unit test cases

Answer (score 8):

I recently learned about Kotlin coroutines and the guy who taught me showed me a good way to solve this problem.

You create an interface that provides contexts, with a default implementation:

```
interface CoroutineContextProvider {
    val main: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main
    val io: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO

    class Default : CoroutineContextProvider
}
```

And you inject this (`CoroutineContextProvider.Default()`) into your presenter constructor, either manually or with an injection framework. Then in your code you use the contexts it provides: `provider.main`; `provider.io`; or whatever you want to define. Now you can happily use `launch` and `withContext` using these contexts from your provider object, knowing that it will work correctly in your app but you can provide different contexts during testing.

From your tests inject a different implementation of this provider, where all of the contexts are `Dispatchers.Unconfined`

```
class TestingCoroutineContextProvider : CoroutineContextProvider {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override val main: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override val io: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
```

When you mock the suspend function, call it wrapped with `runBlocking`, which will ensure that all the action all takes place in the calling thread (your test). It's explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html) (see the section about "Unconfined vs confined Dispatcher").

Answer (score 2):

For others to use, here's the implementation I ended up with.

```
interface Executor {
    fun onMainThread(function: () -> Unit)
    fun onWorkerThread(function: suspend () -> Unit) : Job
}

object ExecutorImpl : Executor {
    override fun onMainThread(function: () -> Unit) {
        launch(UI) { function.invoke() }
    }

    override fun onWorkerThread(function: suspend () -> Unit): Job {
        return async(CommonPool) { function.invoke() }
    }
}
```

I inject the `Executor` in my constructor and use kotlins delegation to avoid boilerplate code:

```
class SomeInteractor @Inject constructor(private val executor: Executor)
    : Interactor, Executor by executor {
    ...
}
```

It's now possible to use the `Executor`-methods interchangeably:

```
override fun getSomethingAsync(listener: ResultListener?) {
    job = onWorkerThread {
        val result = repository.getResult().awaitResult()
        onMainThread {
            when (result) {
                is Result.Ok -> listener?.onResult(result.getOrDefault(emptyList())) :? job.cancel()
                // Any HTTP error
                is Result.Error -> listener?.onHttpError(result.exception) :? job.cancel()
                // Exception while request invocation
                is Result.Exception -> listener?.onException(result.exception) :? job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my test I switch the `Executor` implementation with this.

For unit tests:

```
/**
 * Testdouble of [Executor] for use in unit tests. Runs the code sequentially without invoking other threads
 * and wraps the code in a [runBlocking] coroutine.
 */
object TestExecutor : Executor {
    override fun onMainThread(function: () -> Unit) {
        Timber.d("Invoking function on main thread")
        function()
    }

    override fun onWorkerThread(function: suspend () -> Unit): Job {
        runBlocking {
            Timber.d("Invoking function on worker thread")
            function()
        }
        return mock<Job>()
    }
}
```

For instrumentation tests:

```
/**
 * Testdouble of [Executor] for use in instrumentations tests. Runs the code on the UI thread.
 */
object AndroidTestExecutor : Executor {
    override fun onMainThread(function: () -> Unit) {
        Timber.d("Invoking function on worker thread")
        function()

    }

    override fun onWorkerThread(function: suspend () -> Unit): Job {
        return launch(UI) {
            Timber.d("Invoking function on worker thread")
            function()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make your presenter not know about the `UI` context.
Instead, the presenter should be context-less. 
The presenter should just expose the `suspend` function and let the callers specify the context. 
Then when you call this presenter coroutine function from the View, you call it with `UI` context `launch(UI) { presenter.somethingAsync() }`.
That way when testing the presenter you can run the test with `runBlocking { presenter.somethingAsync() }`

Comment: I tried hat at first but found out that because the logic in the presenter might call the view during the somethingAsync method I run into ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadExceptions. This can only be solved by wrapping all view methods in a launch(UI) call.

Comment: With the accepted solution the presenter actually doesn't know about the context. The AsyncLauncher could also be an interface to fully decouple it.

Comment: But with this approach, you can safely call the view from the presenter. Take a look at first suspend function from this presenter https://github.com/deva666/NewsReader/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/markodevcic/newsreader/articles/ArticlesPresenter.kt . Presenter calls an a coroutine and after the coroutine, it interacts with the View. Everything after async call get's executed on the UI  context.

Comment: I see how this works in your case but in mine it wont. This is because your view holds some of the logic that in my case is controlled by the presenter (ex. noNetworkErrors).

Comment: Really nice looking project by the way. Very easy to read the code.