# Testing coroutines in the presenter class

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I'm struggling to test my presenter which is calling a suspended function from the repository layer as follow:

```
 override fun viewCreated() {
        launch {
            val hasPermission = permissionChecker.execute() //suspended function
            if (hasPermission) {
                foo()
            } else {
                view.bar()
            }
         }
```

The presenter is also extending this interface:

```
interface CoroutinePresenter: CoroutineScope {

val job: Job

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

fun stopAllActiveJobs() {
    coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
}
```

And the suspended function is defined as follow:

```
 suspend fun execute() : Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    return@withContext class.foo()
}
```

Everything is working as expected in the app but when I tried to write some unit test I noticed that whenever I call the piece of code inside *launch* the thread is switched but the test doesn't wait for the execution. This is the implementation of the test:

```
@Test
fun `Test of Suspended Function`() = runBlocking {
    presenter.viewCreated()
    then(view).should().bar()
    ...
}
```

I also added the suggested library for testing `kotlinx-coroutines-test` but the result is still the same with it. I also tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55192949/5382017) suggestion and also implementing something like [this](https://gist.github.com/manuelvicnt/049ce057fa6b5e5c785ec9fff7c22a7c) but still no luck.
I think the problem is the actual creation of another thread whenever the *launch* is invoked in the presenter and the test doesn't actually know how to wait for it. I also tried to return a *Job* and invoking the `job.join()` but it fails with a `NullPointerException`.

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for that:
following [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md) tutorial, I've setup both

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
    ...
}
@After
fun tearDown() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain() // reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher
}
```

And by running the entire *launch* block of the `presenter` class inside a `runBlocking` statement in the test. The problem was related also to a not reported exception inside the suspended function that was actually not *mocked* but it was invisible to my eyes.

Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I strongly recommend that give your coroutineContext as a Parameter like that:

> ```
>   class CoroutinePresenter(coroutineContext: CoroutineContext): CoroutineScope {
>          init{
>                _coroutineContext = coroutineContext
>           }
>
>          override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
>                 get() = _coroutineContext
>
>          // Your Methods
>
>     }
> ```

In your real environment:

> ```
>  @YourScope
>     @Provides
>     fun providesCoroutinePresenter(coroutineContext:CoroutineContext ){
>         return CoroutinePresenter()
>     }
>     @YourScope
>     @Provides
>     fun providesCoroutineContext(){
>         return  Dispatchers.Main + job
>     }
> ```

During the unit test:

> ```
>     @Before
>     fun setUp() {
>        coroutinePresenter  CoroutinePresenter(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
>     }
>
>     @Test
>     fun `Should do something`(){
>          //WHEN
>          coroutinePresenter.doSomething(params)
>          //THEN
>          do your assertions
>     }
> ```

For more please check **SOLID Principles** and for this case **D**

Comment: This is a very good solution but I think using the library provided by the official kotlin team it's actually better as you're going to inject an additional parameter to the presenter class just for the sake of testing. It's of course working as expected.